# converting the difference in vectors to between 0 and 1

Tags: python, math, pygame, trigonometry

I'm working with two unit vectors but not sure how to calculate this. I need it so that if they point in the same direction the answer is 1, opposite directions the answer is 0, perpendicular (either up or down) the answer is 0.5, etc.

Examples:
For two vectors (1,0) and (-1,0) (so, opposite vectors), the answer I get is 0.
For two vectors (1,0) and (1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2)) (so, the unit vector pointing at a 45 degree angle) I get 0.25.
For two vectors (0,1) and (-1,0) (so, perpendicular vectors) I get 0.5

Thank you for any help with this!

Comment: What you are looking for is actually nothing else than the angle between the two vectors. The angle will, of course, be in the range [0, 180°] (or [0, Pi] if expressed in radians). Dividing the result by 180 (or Pi), you get your required result in the range of [0, 1]. Concerning angle between vectors, look for e.g. dot product: _cos alpha = **p** * **q** / (| **p** | * | **q** |)_ while you can omit the lower part if you know you have unit vectors -> It would be dividing by 1 * 1.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read about the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) In general The *dot* product of 2 vectors is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors multiplied by the magnitude (length) of both vectors.

```
dot( A, B ) == | A | * | B | * cos( angle_A_B )
```

This follows, that the *dot* product of 2 unit vectors is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors, because the length of a [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) is 1.

```
uA = normalize( A )
uB = normalize( B )
cos( angle_A_B ) == dot( uA, uB )
```

[image: A dot B]

If 2 normalized vectors point in the same direction, then the dot product is 1, if the point in the opposite direction, the dot product is -1 and if the vectors are perpendicular then the dot product is 0.

In pygame the dot product can be computed by [`math.Vector2.dot()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.dot). If `A` and `B` are [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) objects:

```py
uA = A.normalize()
uB = B.normalize()
AdotB = uA.dot(uB)
```

---

In the example above, `AdotB` is in range [-1.0, 1.0]. `AdotB * 0.5 + 0.5` is in range [0.0, 1.0] and `math.acos(AdotB) / math.pi + 1` maps the angle between `A` and `B` linearly to the range [0.0, 1.0].

---

Furthermore, [`pygame.math.Vector2.angle_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.angle_to) calculates the angle to a given vector in degrees. A value in range [0.0, 2.0] dependent on the angle can be computed by

```py
w = 1 - A.angle_to(B) / 180
```

Comment: Thank you, but that fluctuates between 1 and -1, I need between 1 and 0. But that was very helpful!

Comment: @taijifajin If  `AdotB` is in range [-1, 1], then `AdotB*0.5+0.5` is in range [0, 1].

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for missing that. Thank you, that's perfect!

Comment: @taijifajin From your example with an angle of 45°, it looks like what you want is the angle, not the dot product. So `acos(AdotB) / pi + 1` appears to suit your needs better than `(AdotB + 1) / 2`.

Comment: Thanks Stef, once I started playing around with different numbers I realized none of those were working. This is actually the thing that seems to work (at least for the right, up, left, down, and the 4 points between those):

A = Vector2(1,0)
B = Vector2(5,0)

uA = A.normalize()
uB = B.normalize()

w = 1 - uA.angle_to(uB) / 180
if w > 1:
    w = 2 - w
print(w)

Answer (score 1):

What you essentailly need is the angle of the two vectors, you can the scale that to your `0-1` interval from the `0-pi` interval.

You have the identity:

```
a dot b = norm(a)*norm(b)*cos(gamma), and in this case:
a dot b = cos(gamma), because they are unit vectors.
```

and

```
a dot b = ax*bx+ay*by
```

From this you have `cos(gamma)`, and therefore `gamma`.

Does this help?